# Drupal 7 db_insert error on simple query

Tags: database, insert, drupal-7, syntax-error

I am having an issue inserting an entry with db_insert.  I am 100% certain my table and field names match up, and the values I'm passing are fine and look good in debug output. Yet, I keep getting a syntax error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, fstate, fname, fexpire, size, item) VALUES ('0', '1', '1327451461', '0', '' at line 1

```
<?
$e = array();
$e['id']        = 0;
$e['type']      = exif_imagetype($fullpath);
$e['updated']   = time();
$e['lc']        = 0;
$e['desc']      = $form_state['values']['brand_name'] . ' logo';
$e['fstate']    = EET_BULK_LOCKED;
$e['fname']     = $fif->filename;
$e['fexpire']   = $e['updated'] + (3600 * 24 * 7);
$e['size']      = $fif->filesize;
//   $e['item']      = file_get_contents($fullpath);
$e['item'] = 0;

debug("e = " . print_r($e));   

$dbi = db_insert('eet_bulk');
$dbi->fields($e);


try
{
    $bulk_id = $dbi->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $pe)
{
    form_set_error("dbi bulk item", $pe->getMessage());
}
$dbi = NULL;
```

My db field names match up, and the data outputs fine in debug.

What am I missing?

Comment: It was my field named 'desc', which is a reserved MySQL keyword.  I changed the field name and all is well.

Comment: whaddaya know.. this was exactly my problem. :p

Comment: Damn those reserved words.. thanks for the hint.